# android byte[] data modification

Tags: android, android-camera

I did my own camera app on Android.

1) Configuring camera and preview :

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
// My camera takes landscape picture by befault (Samsung GT-9300).
// But my app is only in portrait mode.
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
// Here to rotate final pict
parameters.set("rotation", 90);

// Some code to define best preview resolution and best picture resolution
... some code ...

// Apply
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

2) StartPreview

```
// Here I see what i want to see... Is there no problem here.
camera.startPreview();
```

3) GetOutputMediaFile()

```
// private function to create empty file which will receive data 
private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
    String NewFolder = "/TEST";
    String StorageDirectory;
    StorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(StorageDirectory + NewFolder);
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("myApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        } else {
            mediaStorageDir.mkdir();
        }
    }

    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss", Locale.FRANCE).format(new Date());

    File photo = new File(StorageDirectory + NewFolder, "photo_" + date + ".jpg");

    return photo;       
}
```

4) Here my problem

```
// camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture) called on onCreate function

// Here this callback
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
    if (pictureFile == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }       
};
```

On my phone, if i go on my gallery, or original my files app, i have thumbnail and photo correctly oriented.

Now if I go, with Root File Manager, on this picture folder, thumbnail is oriented by default (real camera orientation), and same as if I look my picture with my computer.

Then I think my data var (byte[] data) on my onPictureTaken function is not good. 
I think data is like that :

[How I think my var data is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zhVG.jpg)

But I would like to have that as my var data :

[How I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkB3r.jpg)

I know my var data is only byte[] but these cat pictures is to shows how I see my data var.

**Now my questions :**

A) Have I right on how my data variable is ?

B) If yes, can you say me how to do 90° rotation on this "array" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not change the image bits to account for rotation.

Rotation is stored in the JPG `EXIF` image metadata orientation value, so you just need to set the metadata value to match the camera orientation. Read more about this EXIF value and others [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format).

To manage the EXIF data you can use framework class [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html).

Comment: I looked Exif Attribute like getAttribute("TAG_ORIENTATION"), it return null, which means there is no such tag in the JPEG file. Then i tried to setAttribute("TAG_ORIENTATION", "6"), 6 = ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90, then saveAttributes() at the end of onPictureTaken(). But i've same result. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

If the picture shows correctly in your phone's gallery application, it is likely correctly oriented. You can experiment with different values for the [Parameters.setRotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29) and see if they affect what you see in the gallery app.

Some picture viewing programs do not correctly apply the EXIF orientation field, which can lead to them drawing the image incorrectly rotated. If that's the case, changing the orientation field does nothing, since those programs will not work with any orientation value. You'll have to actually rotate the JPEG image, instead of just setting the metadata field, to get them to look correct there.

If you want to do this inside Android, you'll have to decode the byte[] you receive from the camera to a Bitmap (with a [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html), rotate the bitmap, and save the result as a JPEG. You'll lose all the other EXIF metadata (date/time taken, etc) unless you use ExifInterface to write them back. It's also possible to losslessly rotate a JPEG, but I don't know if there are Android libraries for that.